# Is there a limit on the number of requests to Apple to verifyReceipt?

Tags: ios, in-app

We get the user cancels in the next 30 days from our database and we call to Apple one to one

https://buy.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt

We want to call for a list of user cancels in the next 365 days which can be a huge list.

I look for that in the documentation and in google but I couldn't find if there is a limit on the number of requests to Apple.

Does anyone know that?

Comment: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/26393

Comment: @giorashc I found this link but as that user said, there is not mention of query limits and I am not sure Apple let us to call for a huge list. Maybe we will try to do it but I would like to be sure before.

Comment: best way will be contacting apple's support

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After contact Apple's support, there are not query limits.

I have this endpoint implemented several months ago and I make a huge number of requests every day without any problem.

It's the only way to verify the status of each receipt because their webhook doesn't seem reliable.

Comment: It's still any query limits?

Comment: @anton.uspehov There is not query limits.

By the way, Apple has improved their server-to-server notifications so now I would recommend to go for it and implement a webhook:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appstoreservernotifications